# Cumulate values in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, report, accumulate

I've got a Crystal Reports report for accounting the status of invoices.
Now I want to make a cross-tab and count how many invoices were valid in one given month.

This is the easy part. The difficulty comes now:
How can I count how many invoices are valid the next month and add up the previous month?
The previous month must stay visible in the cross tab.
This means that when in one month nothing changes the same value remains as the previous month

It would look like this:

```
                    01-2014         02-2014
Valid                 10              12
Out of time           05              06
Rejected              02              05
```

Answer (score 0):

Instructions:

- Add the date field to the column's section; group by month
- Add the category (e.g. 'Valid') to the row's section
- Add the invoice number to the summarized-field section; change summary to count
- change the record-selection formula to `{table.date} IN [LastFullMonth to MonthToDate]`